# How to reply a question like this: "We are not doing this, correct?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

My first reply to my boss for this question was " Yes, you are correct. We are not doing this" .

Can I also reply this way, "No, we are not doing this." ?

Are these two replies both correct? If so, which one feels more like a native speaker?

Comment: Thanks, Hellion. I can see that my first question is kind covered in the question you linked. However, my 2nd question regarding which expression feels more like a native speaker is not covered. So, I still hope some one could help me with that in my question.

Comment: Your first is quite clear.